# Filter collection by array property inside of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter a collection on a property which is an array. For example, I have a collection:

```
const collection = [
  {
    name: 'one',
    type: ['BRANCH']
  },
  {
    name: 'Two',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
  {
    name: 'Three',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
]
```

And I have a filter which is also an array:

```
const filter = ['BRANCH']
```

Now I am trying to return only items from the collection which match the filter array. I have the following code which I am trying to refactor:

```
const filtered = [];

collection.forEach((item) => {
  item.type.forEach((type) => {
    if (filters.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
      filtered.push(item);
    }
  })
})

console.log(filtered);
```

Is there a better way to compare these arrays (`item.type` and `filter`) inside of a loop to return only the matching items in the collection?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hhhx5b)

Comment: What about the case that `obj.type` or `filter` contain more items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic probably doesn't achieve what you want - if more than one item in a `type` matches something in `filter`, the array item will be pushed *twice* (or more).

For example:

```js
const collection = [
  {
    name: 'one',
    type: ['BRANCH']
  },
  {
    name: 'Two',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
  {
    name: 'Three',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
  {
    name: 'one',
    type: ['BRANCH', 'FOO']
  },
];
const filters = ['BRANCH', 'FOO']
const filtered = [];
collection.forEach((item) => {
  item.type.forEach((type) => {
    if (filters.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
      filtered.push(item);
    }
  })
})
console.log(filtered);
```

Rather, you might use `Array.prototype.filter` and check whether *`.some`* of the `type`s are included in the `filter` array:

```js
const collection = [
  {
    name: 'one',
    type: ['BRANCH']
  },
  {
    name: 'Two',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
  {
    name: 'Three',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
]
const filter = ['BRANCH'];

console.log(
  collection.filter(({ type }) => (
    type.some(item => filter.includes(item))
  ))
);
```

That's assuming you want items in the result if *some* of the `type`s are included in `filter`. If you want to check whether *every* item of `filter` is in the `type` array, use `Array.prototype.every` over the `filter` array:

```js
const collection = [
  {
    name: 'one',
    type: ['BRANCH']
  },
  {
    name: 'Two',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
  {
    name: 'Three',
    type: ['OTHER']
  },
]
const filter = ['BRANCH'];

console.log(
  collection.filter(({ type }) => (
    filter.every(item => type.includes(item))
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` to filter the object, use `every` and `includes` to check array equality:

```
const filtered = collection.filter(obj =>
    obj.type.every(item => filter.includes(item))
);
```

Which reads: filter objects from the array `collection` where each object's `type` array is a subset of the array `filter`.

**Example:**

```js
const collection = [ { name: 'one', type: ['BRANCH'] }, { name: 'Two', type: ['OTHER'] }, { name: 'Three', type: ['OTHER'] } ];

const filter = ['BRANCH'];

const filtered = collection.filter(obj =>
    obj.type.every(item => filter.includes(item))
);

console.log(filtered);
```